# Displaying all application errors in a view

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning `ASP.NET Core` with `MVC` pattern and I didn't find anything useful related to this argument.

Actually I'm looking for a way to handle all the application errors inside a single `View`. The first thing that I did was create the `View` for display the error, this is the design (pretty simple though):

```
<h2>@(ViewBag.ErrorMessage == null ? "An error happened" : "" + @ViewBag.ErrorMessage + "")</h2>
```

and this is the `Error` controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(string errorMessage)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Essentially, I used the `ViewBag` for valorize a property called `ErrorMessage` which contains the parameter `errorMessage`.

Let me show an example of this logic for the email confirmation:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string token)
{
    if (userId == null || token == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    if (user != null)
    {
       if (user.EmailConfirmed)
       { 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { errorMessage = "Email already confirmed" });
       }

       IdentityResult result;

       try
       {
           result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
       }
       catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { errorMessage = ex.Message });
       }

       if (result.Succeeded)
       {
           //TODO: Send another email
           return View("ConfirmEmail", user);
       }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { errorMessage = "Utser not found" });
    }
```

Now, I'm not an expert yet of `ASP.NET Core` so I don't know if my practice is good enough for a production environment, someone could maybe propose a better way or improve my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I see no problem design-like or code-like, in the point of view of the user, It can be frustrating.

I guess the method `ConfirmEmail` is called from a form.

So, imagine how frustrating it is if you fill a form and if there is any error in this form, it redirects you to the Error View ?

Imo, Error display should be handled by Javascript/Html/Css on the same page which thrown the error to avoid losing any data from user's pov. Like, displaying a notification or even an error message below the field.

How you display the error should be specific of the error.